# How to get parameters from Route in ZF2 module? (class Module, function onBootstrap())

Tags: zend-framework2

In controller I can get parameters from route using `$this->params()->fromRoute('param1')`
How can I do that in Module OnBootstrap() function?

```
namespace MyModule;

use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $event)
    {
        // here I need to get parameter from route
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You can't access the route parameters during bootstrap since the routing hasn't happened yet. What you'd need to do is attach a listener to the `MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER` event in order to wait for the routing to happen and then fetch the route parameters.

Comment: oops, meant `EVENT_ROUTE`

Comment: I want to redirect to route "installer" if current route is not "installer"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As user2257808 said in his comment, onBootstrap is called before routing takes place, so there is not any RouteMatch to get.  He suggested attaching to EVENT_RENDER, that may be too late in your case.

I would do something like this, attaching to `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH`.

**MyModule\Module.php**

```
class Module {
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {

        $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
            function($e){
               var_dump($e->getRouteMatch());
                exit;
            }
         );

    }
}
```