# getResponse in ZF2 Bootstrap

Tags: logging, soap, zend-framework2, bootstrapping

I am trying to get the response in onBootstrap function in zf2. It gives me the getRequest object in detail i.e. the Soap request that had been made. But it does not give me the getResponse object competely i.e. Soap response. Only thing it returns as a response is **HTTP/1.1 200 OK**. The bootstrap code is as follows:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{

        $app = $e->getApplication();

        $em  = $app->getEventManager();

        $response = new Response();
        $logger = $sm->get('Zend\Log\Logger');


            $params = $e->getParams();      
        $logger->debug(sprintf(
                'Route event with route %s with name %s, response: %s ',
                 json_encode($params),
          $e->getApplication()->getRequest(),
          $e->getApplication()->getResponse()

        ));
    }
```

Comment: onBootstrap would only be Module Bootstrapping. You'd probably be wanting to attach this method onto a later stage of the applications lifecycle. See [A list of ZF2 Events by Rob Allen](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/a-list-of-zf2-events/)

Comment: Thanks very much Sam. Should I attach it to onDispatch ?

Comment: Can you please give an example ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223705/how-to-get-parameters-from-route-in-zf2-module-class-module-function-onbootst/16229360#16229360 May help you, haven't done it myself

Comment: stil the same result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was Able to solve the issue by adding the line setResponse(true) in Soap Server.