# Access url parameters inside onBootstrap method

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I wanted to execute a method for each page in my Zend 2 application. Thus, i added it to `Application`'s `Module.php` onBootstrap method.

Now i need to know which controller is being called and rest of the parameters (action, id ...).

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $controllerName = ''; //how to get ?
    $actionName = ''; //how to get ?
    $id = ''; //how to get ?

    ...
    myMethod($controllerName, $actionName, $id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution - [How to get parameters from Route in ZF2 module? (class Module, function onBootstrap())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223705/how-to-get-parameters-from-route-in-zf2-module-class-module-function-onbootst)

```
class Module {
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {

        $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
            function($e){
               var_dump($e->getRouteMatch());
                exit;
            }
         );

    }
}
```